# Nicedit : local upload works but don't insert

Tags: javascript, jquery, nicedit

I'm using the last version of Nicedit with the `nicUpload` plugin.
I customized the toolbar with the  `upload`  button, created a PHP upload script and then edit the `uploadURI` and the `nicURI` parameters in the script.

- the image is well uploaded to my server
- the PHP script returns a json data
- the "loading" animation fades out but .. the image is not inserted into the `TextArea`.

[image]

Am I missing an event?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this issue is solved...
In fact the img was well inserted but with 'width="0"'.